# Cairo Dock - Chrome Browser - Unity Launcher Icon and Application sync

Tags: launcher, google-chrome, cairo-dock

My problem is as follows

1. I use cairo dock as a replacement for the Unity Launcher on Ubuntu
2. I used chrome desktop shortcuts to make some pseudo desktop apps of some webapps (like outlook exchange)
3. I want these webapps to pick up the Icon I give them, the Unity launcher picks up the icon I allocate to it, minimizing and clicking on the icon reopens the existing window
4. But on Cairo dock clicking the icon opens a chrome window and clicking on the icon again opens a new chrome window instead of briging the open one into focus

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to emulate unity launcher's behaviour with cairo dock?

Comment: I'm running into this same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I just ditched cairo-dock

Comment: What did you use as a replacement that doesn't have the same issue?

Comment: The stock unity launcher :(

Comment: @Bryan have you ever tried JWM?

Answer (score 0):

you can use an existent icon of the launcher. In example, i used Firefox launcher, right click on icon and changed his settings.
I downloaded google chrome icon from internet in PNG format, then i put it into launcher config.